# I tried to add border-radius to my div element but not working

Tags: css, linear-gradients, border-image, border-radius

I have a div element I wants to apply border radius of 100px, so that it will be in a circular shape. Unfortunately the border radius is not applying to the div element. The CSS selector looks like this:

```
  .battery-circle {
  border: 4px solid;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-radius: 30em;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, rgba(163,61,255,1) 84%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per W3C spec:

> **A box's backgrounds, but not its border-image, are clipped to the appropriate curve (as determined by ‘background-clip’)**. Other
> effects that clip to the border or padding edge (such as ‘overflow’
> other than ‘visible’) also must clip to the curve. The content of
> replaced elements is always trimmed to the content edge curve. Also,
> the area outside the curve of the border edge does not accept mouse
> events on behalf of the element.

So as a work around you could try something like this:

```css
.battery-circle {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-radius: 30em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), 
                    linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, rgba(163,61,255,1) 84%);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="battery-circle">test</div>
```